# How to extract time out of text in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, regex

I have the following issue and I would appreciate your help. I need to get the time values out of this string:

```
SomeText 02/02/2020 9:00 AM-02/02/2020 9:15 AM;"Text" 02/02/2020 10:45 AM-02/02/2020 11:15 AM;"Text" 02/02/2020 12:45 PM-02/02/2020 1:00 PM;
```

The pattern and length are not consistent. But time always comes after the date.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To get the time out of timestamps found in mixed text**, try this formula
*(where `A2` is the cell with our text)*:

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"\D|(../../.... (.:.\d|..:..) (PM|AM))|[0-9]","♜$1"),"♜|(../../.... )","♞"),"♞",1,1)
```

Functions used:

- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)

---

***Mention***: I noticed that you also posted your question on 
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60350885/1527780) as well where you also got another variation of a working solution.
So to use the best of both worlds (shorter, returns a number a well instead of a text), you can try this:

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B5,"\D|(\d+:\d+\s[AP]M)|[0-9]","♜$1"),"♜")
```

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly

Comment: Great. Try the new formula as well.